# Mount issue for EBS at EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

For historical reason we have 2 EBS drive for our application (which is an EC2 instance, using Amazon2 Linux), one needs to mount as

/data

And the other need to mount as

/data/inhouse

However, after we create a new build of the application, we found it is quite often that "/data/inhouse" cannot mount automatically but need to manually mount it. Not sure if there is any solution to that?

BTW below are the error log when start

```
xfs_growfs: XFS_IOC_FSGROWFSDATA xfsctl failed: Input/output error
meta-data=/dev/nvme1n1           isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=19660800 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=78643200, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=38400, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your 2nd drive is not formatted. By default only the first disk has a filesystrm on it, all other disks must be formatted (`mkfs.xfs`) before use. This can be done automatically in some startup script.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in fact it is formatted, and it will work if I restart the host a few time. However, not sure how can I prevent the try restart

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure the order in which the disks are mounted. First you must mount `/data` and only then `/data/inhouse`

Typically with `/etc/fstab` it can be quite random but you can enforce the order with `requires-mounts-for` fstab option.

Check out this article for more details: [How to manage order of disk drives mounting](https://www.thegeeksearch.com/how-to-manage-order-of-mounting-in-centos-rhel-78-using-systemd/)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back but look like AWS EBS vol use a difference way to mount, it is only "/" at my fstab.

And yes, I exactly looking for something like "requires-mounts-for" for EBS config

Comment: @CarfieldYim then your system is probably using [`systemd.mount`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) rather than fstab. The same article linked in my response talks about that too. For more info google something like *mounting disks with systemd* and come back if you have any issues with that.